# Your connection is not private - NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm using: `Huawei Nexus 6p` with `Android 7.1.1` and latest stable version of `Google Chrome Browser`, and whenever I'm trying to access my website and I'm getting:

> Your connection is not private (see screenshot)

I removed my website name out of screenshot(s):

[image] [image]

Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a website releated problem?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје it most likely is, but it could be a device/software problem as well (missing CA certs pre-installed by the vendor).

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје yes, as I'm able to access it from other devices without any issues.

Comment: @GiantTree nothing is missing (CA certs are included) and SSL works properly from desktop and other devices as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to address my issue with following steps:

- [chrome://net-internals/#hsts](http://chrome://net-internals/#hsts)
- input `FQDN` in `Delete domain` and followed by `Delete` button.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be an issue on your side:
**Make sure you are not using a proxy, VPN or any other kind of *traffic redirection*.**

Inform the owner of the website that because of [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), you are not able to visit his website.
He needs to configure a trusted SSL certificate that is neither self-signed, nor expired (read as: *You can't connect via plain HTTP for the next year, until the HSTS entry on your device expires. This implies that the site in question was not added to the HSTS preload lists of any browser vendor*).

The error you presented implies an untrusted certificate chain, with the certificate used by the Certificate Authority not being trusted.
This could be because of a private certificate authority (often used for VPNs to revoke certificates) or an outdated system configuration (CA certs are updated regularly, CAs like *Let's Encrypt* are very young and switch their CA certificates/add new ones once they are approved).

> **If you are the web admin**: Configure your Web Server to serve HTTPS requests with a valid certificate.

Comment: I'm an admin) SSL is configured (with valid certificate) and even though I took out `HSTS`  configuration, I'm still experiencing an error.

Comment: @alexus you can't *take out HSTS*. HSTS is enforced for a long time (configurable, should be at least 6 months) and a client won't connect to a server without HSTS (or even HTTPS). Basically: Once HSTS is enabled, you can't disable it.

Comment: sure you can) just follow my answer I just did it (without waiting for 6 month).

Comment: Now tell all your visitors prior to the removal to do this.

Comment: this is private website and my users are numbered (so that's not an issue), however I do see what you're saying..